# ListView not populated

Tags: android

I have class that extends `FragmentActivity`, also I have a layout xml file that contains a `ListView` **listview_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="310dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menuList"
        android:layout_width="310dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="2dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Note the id of the `ListView`, **menuList**

From my java code, I grab this listview this way:

```
private View getElementFromView(int layout, int element) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        return view.findViewById(element);
    }
```

This method will return a `View` to me, and I do a check in order to see if this `View` is an instance of `ListView`

```
    View v = getElementFromView(R.layout.listview_layout, R.id.menuList);
    if(v instanceof ListView) {
        Log.v("View: ", "This view is an instance of a ListView"); 
        ListView lv = (ListView)v; 
        String[] listItems = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}; 
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
    }
```

As you can see, i want to set an `Adapter` to this `ListView`, this should populate the `ListView` with the text Item 1, Item 2 and so on..

What I dont understand is why the listview doesn't show up at all? I guess its since the `ListView` is not populated at all, but why isn't it populated?

Edit:

I should also mentioned that this project is marked as a Library. This is the interesting parts of`BaseWindow.java`

```
  public class BaseWindow extends SlidingFragmentActivity {
        public void InitializeWindow(Activity act, int layoutResourceId, int menuResourceId, String windowTitle)  {
                    super.setContentView(layoutResourceId); 
                    super.setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);  
                    this.menuResourceId = menuResourceId; 
                    this.act = act; 
                    initializeSlidingMenu();
                    setWindowTitle(windowTitle); 
         }

         public void initializeSlidingMenu()  {

            this.setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
            this.setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
            getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
            getSlidingMenu().setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
            getSlidingMenu().setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
            getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.listview_layout);
            getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
            getSlidingMenu().setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);

            View v = getElementFromView(R.layout.listview_layout, R.id.menuList);
            if(v instanceof ListView) {
                Log.v("View: ", "This view is an instance of a ListView"); 
                ListView lv = (ListView)v; 
                String[] listItems = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}; 
                lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));
                //lv.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(this, menuResourceId));
            }       
        }
    }
```

This class is called from another project in my workspace, and yes I've included the class/project over as a Library:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseWindow {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.InitializeWindow(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main, R.menu.slide_menu, "Home"); 

    }
}
```

Everything works quite well, but the listview is not populated at all. Hope this gives you an idea on what am trying to achieve.

Comment: do you get an error, can you see your logging (Log.v("View: ", "This view is an instance of a ListView");)?

Comment: can you see "View: This view is an instance of a ListView" in logcat ?
do you see the color # 00FFFF of the list view on the screen?

Comment: @Nickolaus No Exceptions, no errors. And yes the message is logged to LogCat.

Comment: your xml looks suspicious.  can you try removing FrameLayout. or whats their parent view type?

Comment: Can you post your FragmentActivity onCreate? Specifically the setContentView part

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can see the view created here `View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);` is never attached to the window.

You have to call setContentView(View v) or something to put this layout on the screen

Comment: This sounds correct. Could you please take a look at my edit above, and suggest where I should do so? Thanks!

Comment: `getSlidingMenu().setContent(R.layout.listview_layout); View v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menuList);`  or if you want to set the behind menu use `getSlidingMenu().setMenu(int);`

Comment: Thanks. I've actually setted the menu:  `getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.listview_layout);` all I want to do is to bind an adapter to this `listView`. Do I need to add this view once more after this?

Comment: so just call after that `View list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menuList);` and `list.setAdapter(...`

Comment: this method you created `getElementFromView` is creating a new view hierarchy. But in reality you just want to find the ListView in the existing hierarchy.

Comment: if I use the findViewById method I will just get a `NullPointerException`.. Dont know why, tho.

Comment: are you calling it AFTER `getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.listview_layout);` ??

Comment: Yes: `getSlidingMenu().setMenu(R.layout.listview_layout);
   
   ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menuList);
   String[] listItems = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}; 
   lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));`

Comment: I've never worked with this SliddingMenu extending the activity, I just went on the easier approach of inflating and attaching it to the activity. I can't understand why it's not finding your view, but you could try ask directly to the menu using `getSlidingMenu().findViewById(...)` but at that moment that's a guesswork of me.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this, I've took a easier approach and created the ListView directly in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is working correctly and all items are shown, the problem is that the FrameLayout is laying on top of your LinearLayout.

Comment: from the id of the framelayout i'd imagine the intent is to make a transparent overlay or something. Nevertheless, i think you're right.

Comment: yes, if the type of parent container if "frame". this depends only on the type of the parent container.